# Why raise a Created event in a Smart Contract constructor?

Tags: events

Reading through the Bancor code I see this:

```
function SmartToken(string _name, string _symbol, uint8 _decimals)
    public
    ERC20Token(_name, _symbol, _decimals)
{
    NewSmartToken(address(this));
}
```

What is the purpose of raising an event in the constructor? What value could it be adding to a client? Is it just an easy way to get the block the contract was created at? I imagine this is doable in any case.

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, it's not useful for the entity creating the contract, so I imagine it's for something else that wants to know about *all* the `SmartToken`s that exist. (E.g. a central directory.)

Comment: Shouldn't the central directory be raising the event in that case? If I have web3 listening to the central directory for events, does that even let me listen for events that child contracts raise?

Comment: I think you're assuming the directory does the deploying, but I'm assuming they want to be notified when _anyone_ deploys the contract.

Comment: Hmmm. I see. So it's possible to listen for a general event on the blockchain not listening to a specific smart contract for the event?

Comment: Yes. You don't need to listen to events from a specific address.